# QTableView - not allow user to edit cell

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtableview

I created a QTableView with a QSqlTableModel.
By standard, double-clicking on the cells will mark them and the user can edit them.
I want, that the user isn't allowed to do that. He is allowed to mark the whole row by clicking on a single cell, but not to edit the cell.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Depending on whether you are coding everything or doing things in the designer, set

- `editTriggers` to `QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers`
- `selectionBehavior` to `QAbstractItemView::SelectRows`
- optionally set `selectionMode` to `QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection` if you want the user to select exactly one row

on the tableview object the appropriate calls will all be prefixed with `set` e.g `setEditTriggers()` in the Designer you can find these option in the `AbstractItemView` section

Comment: it's called QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers, QAbstractItemView::SelectRows and QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection, but it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: but setting it back to AllEditTriggers, is not allowing to edit anymore

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

Answer (score 4):

Toggle off the table item's `ItemIsEditable` bit.  e.g.:

```
QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem(...);
...
item->setFlags(item->flags() &= ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you will want to use:

```
void QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate ( QAbstractItemDelegate * delegate )
```

And then create a class that inherits from `QItemDelegate` like in [this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/model-view-delegate.html) example.
Editing your class to have

```
QWidget * QItemDelegate::createEditor ( QWidget * parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
```

return `NULL`

or use:

```
table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

You will also want to look at

```
void setSelectionBehavior ( QAbstractItemView::SelectionBehavior behavior )
```

With the parameter: `QAbstractItemView::SelectRows`

For reference:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtableview.html